# DatePicker Error in Angular JS due to UTC

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have selected the 12th of September 2014 in the UI.

Following is the code

```
    ctrl.$formatters.push(function (modelValue) {
            console.log(modelValue);
            var dt = new Date(modelValue);
            dt.setMinutes(dt.getMinutes() + dt.getTimezoneOffset());
            console.log(dt)
            return dt;
        });
```

The two console logs i see are the following.

1. 09/11/2014
2. Wed Sep 10 2014 18:30:00 GMT+0530 (IST)

Am not sure why the conversion from UTC to local is not carried out correctly.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not clear what you are trying to do.  The input does not have a time.  Do you want to add the current time of the day to the arbitrary date?  Or do you just want a local representation of the date?  I'm geussing the latter.

Instead of `dt.setMinutes(...)` and the following two lines, replace all three lines with:

```
return dt.toLocaleDateString();
```

If you ARE trying to set the time to now on whatever date is input (I don't know why...) but you might try:

```
dt.setTime( new Date().getTime() );
```

instead of the `setMinutes(...)` line.

then you can 
    `return dt.toLocaleString;`

All date objects are stored as miliseconds since, like 1972.  It is best to use the built in Date object methods to get what you want from it. [Here are the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/prototype#Methods) for reference.